# MATLAB - Surf Plot data structure

Tags: matlab, plot

I have done calculations with 2 different methods. For those calculations I have varied 2 parameters: x and y

In the end, I have calculated the % ERROR between both methods, for each variation.
Now I want to create a 3D surface plot from the results:

```
x -> on x axis
y -> on y axis
Error -> on z axis
```

Here is a sample of the data:

```
A = [
                   -0.1111                     1.267          9.45680081826912
                   -0.1111                       2.6          212.361735695025
                     -0.25                     1.533          40.5729362609655
                     -0.25                     2.867          601.253624894196
                   -0.4286                         1          0.12116749607863
                   -0.4286                       3.4          79.6948438921078
                   -0.6667                     2.067          33.3495544017519
                   -0.6667                     3.667          141.774875517481
                        -1                       2.6       -0.0399171449531781
                   0.09091                     1.533            163.7083541414 ];
```

But, when I try to plot it with surf function:

```
x = A(:,1);
y = A(:,2);
z = A(:,3);

surf(x,y,z)
```

, I get an error:

```
Error using surf (line 75)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector
Error in ddd (line 27)
surf(x,y,z)
```

Can you help me with a code that can restructure the data in the format acceptable for the surf function?

P.S. - I am currently trying to write some sample code with my first attempts. I will post it as soon as I get to somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`surf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) function needs a grid of `X,Y`-values as input. Your data however is simply three vectors with some combinations, not a full grid. As described in the documentation, the [`meshgrid`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) function is often helpful to create such grid matrices. Use the `unique` function to select all unique values in `x` and `y` and create matrices of all possible combinations:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(unique(x),unique(y));
```

To create a `Z` matrix which fits the `[X,Y]` grid, the [`griddata`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) function is helpful:

```
Z = griddata(x,y,z,X,Y);
```

Now you can call `surf` with the grid matrices as input:

```
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

Answer (score 0):

create the grid for the first and second column and calculate Z using your formula.
help meshgrid in MATLAB

Comment: That wouldn't work as there is a separate software that does the calculations and running it takes several days. I cannot simply re-run the calculations. I need to reorder the data.

Comment: In that case, I think it is not possible to get a surface plot as error depend on both variables x and y. Surface plot needs matrix instead of vector. Other option could be scatter3 or barplot.

Comment: You are correct in that a surface plot needs a matrix, but I beg to differ that it can't be done. @hbaderts answer explains it perfectly.