# MatLab 3-vector plot/mesh with colour-scale

Tags: matlab, vector, plot, 3d

I have three vectors (22257x1). I want to plot these in a 3D mesh/wireframe with a colour corresponding to the 'Z'-value.

My efforts so far:

- plot3(): allows for only one colour
- scatter3(): does not connect the points
- mesh/surf: require matrixes instead of vectors (for Z at least)

  - magic()/reshape() for fitting the vectors to the mesh/surf functions did not work for me, also for gridding, memory was not enough...
- Many snippets I could find on the www (inc. StackOverflow)

Could anyone please help?

Comment: How about something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596988/matlab-surf-plot-data-structure/30597634#30597634) to use `surf`?

Comment: Is your data regular?

Comment: Yes, normal values if that is what you mean...