# use matlab's surf function on three vectors without equidistant points

Tags: matlab, interpolation, surface

I ran an optimization function over a surface `z` defined by two parameters (`x`,`y`). For each iteration, I stored the `x,y,z` values in a vector form. 
I would like to plot `z` using matlab's `surf` function, but this requires that `z` is a matrix of size `(length(x), length(y))`.

I found a few ways to do this using `meshgrid`, but this would require that my points in `x` and `y` are uniformly spaced. Because they are the result of my optimization process (annealing with some randomness in the step size), the points in `x` and `y` are not equally spaced.
Is there a good way to turn my `z` vector into a corresponding matrix?

Comment: possible dublicate? [This might work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596988/matlab-surf-plot-data-structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are after [`griddata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html):

> The `griddata` function interpolates the surface at the query points specified by (`xq`,`yq`) and returns the interpolated values, `vq`. The surface always passes through the data points defined by `x` and `y`.